# changing button tag border color

Tags: html

I have put an image in border-less `button` tag. When the button is selected with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, a brown border appears around the image. How do I change color of that rectangle from brown to white. Is is possible to have a white rectangle with inner and outer shadow of blue.

HTML

```
<td align=center valign=middle>
  <figure>
    <button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none">
        <img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png">
    </button>
    <figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font>

    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</td>
```

**EDIT:**

[image]

I can change highlight color by using `style=outline-color:white`

HTML

```
<html>

    <body>
        <tr>
            <td align=center valign=middle>
                <figure>
                    <button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none;outline-color:white;">
                        <img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png">
                    </button>
                    <figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font>

                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </td>
            <td align=center valign=middle>
                <figure>
                    <button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none;outline-color:white;">
                        <img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png">
                    </button>
                    <figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font>

                    </figcaption>
                </figure>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

Here is my initial page load image and if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> I get a highlight similar to what is shown

[image]

How do I increase the rectangle width.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button"

    value="Button with border"

    style="color: #07c;

        border: 2px solid #07c;

        padding: 2px 5px;" />
```

Visit this [link](http://carpe.ambiprospect.com/buttons/formbuttons.htm#) for more details.

Comment: you mean to say i have to replace                                    <button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none"><img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png" > </button> with <input type="button"

    value="Button with border"

    style="color: #07c;

        border: 2px solid #07c;

        padding: 2px 5px;" />

Comment: thanks for your reply. i just checked with code you had given me to try you know what happens. initially i get blue rectangle when i select image using tab key i get white inner and outer lines with blue rectangle. i wanted something like this...... i dont want any border to be seen initially when image is selected i want rectangle with shadow effect as i mentioned. hope i am clear

Comment: I have added a link. visit it, I hope you will get the answer.

Comment: thank you so much sandy. i didnt notice anyways i will try that and get back to you

Comment: hey sandy as i had mentioned i could change highlight color to white using this property style="outline-color:white;" but i am not able to change width of highlight. if i use outline-width property it draws rectangle around image initially when page loads which i dont want. i want rectangle to be seen only when i give focus to button using tab key. how do i achieve this. please help me

Comment: Can you post your updated code? You can online put code here http://www.jsfiddle.net/jAxg9/

Comment: <td align=center valign=middle >
<figure>
<button style="background-color:black; height:160px;width:160px ; border:none;outline-color:white;"><img src="F:\rashmi\icons_tv\Help_Normal.png" onfocus="zoom('57px','120px','96px','136px',this);"
onblur="zoom('57px','120px','57px','120px',this);" > </button>
<figcaption><font size="5" color="white" style="font-weight:bold"><center>help</center></font></figcaption>
</figure>                                  copy this code twice inside body tag so that you get exact idea what i meant. when you move between buttons using tab key you get white rectangle.

Comment: Actually i dont have your image. So can you add your image also?

Comment: how do i add image???? sorry to ask you such question but i didnt find any way to attach image.

Comment: Click on edit to ur ques. And click to image on toolbar for uploading the image.

Comment: i cant upload image as i dont have reputation more than 10. :( wat to do ?

Comment: take some image just for testing na.just take 2 buttons with some image loaded as i have mentioned before. try using tab key to focus u can see white highlight. i think with out image also you can test. im sorry

Comment: sandy i am confused now..... my question was how do i change width of highlight rectangle(white rectangle appears around image when tab key pressed) but you code prints alert message when image is clicked.

Comment: Use border:None 8px; You can use any value in place of 8px. And border style None or Solid n other styles.

Comment: setting border:8px as no effect if i set border-width:8px it will display border around image and when i use tab key to select that button i get white rectangle around border. my requirement is i dont want border but i want thick highlight rectangle by default it takes value 1. if i try to set it using outline-width:3px it gives me same effect as one i get using border. hope you got my point

Comment: I am not getting you, what you actually wanna.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
[custom_button text="Custom Button" title="Custom Button" url="http://www.your_link_goes_here..." size="medium" bg_color="#FF5C00" text_color="#FFFFFF" align="left" target="_self"]
```

Comment: [custom_button text="Small Custom Button" title="Small Custom Button" url="http://www.your_link_goes_here..." size="small" bg_color="#FF5C00" text_color="#FFFFFF" align="left" target="_self"]

Comment: You should be more descriptive in your answer, add references and format your code accordingly. Just adding a line of code isn't sufficient.